# PHP error pushes Job in Delayed queue while --tries=0 is used

Tags: laravel, queue, lumen, supervisord, lumen-5.2

I am using supervisor to run jobs on my lumen 5.2 setup. My supervisor conf. look like this

```
[program:laravel-worker]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php /var/www/app/artisan queue:work --
queue=server_level,app_level --tries=0 -vvv  --daemon
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=web_user
numprocs=20
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/var/www/app/storage/logs/worker.log
```

when a job fails due to PHP error, Lumen inserts it in delayed queue and tries to run it indefinitely. I have used --tries=0 and expect a job should be failed in case of any error but it keeps re-running forever.

Comment: hi saqil can i get your email need some help regarding netsuite thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even if you don't specify the `--tries` option, it takes the value `0` as default. Which means jobs will be attempted indefinitely till they're successful. If you want to prevent the jobs from running again after failure, then set the value to 1.

```
--tries=1
```